# Fill in a value whenever character appears in data.table object

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` object and basically what I'd like to do is update the data table whenever a particular `ID_Type` and `BUYER/SELLER` character value occurs. As an example, I have a `data.table` as given here:

```
ID_Type    |   BUYER   |    SELLER
------------------------------------------------
   1       |           |    Joe
   0       |   Peter   |              
   1       |   Peter   |               
   1       |   Sam     |   
   1       |   Peter   |            
   0       |           |    Mark     
   1       |   Tai     |             
   1       |   Tai     |              
   1       |           |    Mark
```

The `dput` output is below:

```
structure(list(ID_Type = c("1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", 
"1", "1"), BUYER = c(" ", "Peter", "Peter", "Sam", "Peter", " ", 
"Tai", "Tai", " "), SELLER = c("Joe", " ", " ", " ", " ", "Mark", 
" ", " ", "Mark")), .Names = c("ID_Type", "BUYER", "SELLER"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000009c60788>)
```

Now, whenever the `ID_Type` in a row is `0` for a particular `BUYER` or `SELLER` I would like to ensure that every instance of that particular `BUYER` or `SELLER` in the data table has an `ID_Type` of `0` in later rows. For example, the `BUYER` Peter has an `ID_Type` of `0` in the 2nd row, so whenever Peter occurs later in the data table in the `BUYER` column I want to change every Peter's `ID_Type` to `0`, with the same thing happening to the `SELLER` Mark

So basically, the new data table that I want should look like the one below:

```
ID_Type    |   BUYER   |    SELLER
------------------------------------------------
   1       |           |    Joe
   0       |   Peter   |               
   0       |   Peter   |               
   1       |   Sam     |   
   0       |   Peter   |            
   0       |           |    Mark     
   1       |   Tai     |             
   1       |   Tai     |                
   0       |           |    Mark
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this

```
library(data.table)

aaa <- structure(list(ID_Type = c("1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1"), 
                      BUYER = c(" ", "Peter", "Peter", "Sam", "Peter", " ", "Tai", "Tai", " "), 
                      SELLER = c("Joe", " ", " ", " ", " ", "Mark", " ", " ", "Mark")), 
                 .Names = c("ID_Type", "BUYER", "SELLER"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))



aaa[BUYER != " ", ID_Type := ID_Type[1], by = BUYER]
aaa[SELLER != " ", ID_Type := ID_Type[1], by = SELLER]
aaa
    #    ID_Type BUYER SELLER
    # 1:       1          Joe
    # 2:       0 Peter       
    # 3:       0 Peter       
    # 4:       1   Sam       
    # 5:       0 Peter       
    # 6:       0         Mark
    # 7:       1   Tai       
    # 8:       1   Tai       
    # 9:       0         Mark
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a little helper function. I'd also replace your space strings `" "` with real missing values:

```
dd[BUYER == " ", BUYER := NA]
dd[SELLER == " ", SELLER := NA]

foo = function(x) {
  if (any(x == 0)) return(rep("0", length(x)))
  return(x)
}
dd[!is.na(BUYER), ID_Type := foo(ID_Type), by = BUYER]
dd[!is.na(SELLER), ID_Type := foo(ID_Type), by = SELLER]
dd
#    ID_Type BUYER SELLER
# 1:       1    NA    Joe
# 2:       0 Peter     NA
# 3:       0 Peter     NA
# 4:       1   Sam     NA
# 5:       0 Peter     NA
# 6:       0    NA   Mark
# 7:       1   Tai     NA
# 8:       1   Tai     NA
# 9:       0    NA   Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP has accepted [GL_Li's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999090/3817004) which obviously returns the expected result for the given sample dataset I doubt that it implements OP's requirements correctly.

The OP has requested (emphasis mine)

> whenever the `ID_Type` in a row is *0* for a particular `BUYER` or
>   `SELLER`, every instance of that particular `BUYER` or `SELLER` in the
>   data table has an `ID_Type` of 0 *in later rows*.

If above specification is to be taken literally to reflect OP's intentions truely then [GL_Li's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999090/3817004) fails in 3 points:

1. It changes `ID_Type` in *all* rows although the OP has specified to change it only in *later* rows.
2. If the first value of `ID_Type` in a group is *not* 0 then subsequent occurrences of 0 are ignored.
3. It changes also other values than 0 (assuming that `ID_Type` will become either be 0 or 1 but not any other value)

I have added a few rows to the sample dataset to demonstrate the effect:

```
DT2
```

> ```
>     ID_Type BUYER SELLER
>  1:       1          Joe
>  2:       0 Peter       
>  3:       1 Peter       
>  4:       1   Sam       
>  5:       1 Peter       
>  6:       0         Mark
>  7:       1   Tai       
>  8:       1   Tai       
>  9:       1         Mark
> 10:       0   Tai       
> 11:       1   Tai       
> 12:       2   Sam       
> 13:       3   Tom       
> 14:       2   Tom
> ```

Applying [GL_Li's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999090/3817004) on `DT2`

```
DT2[BUYER != "", ID_Type := ID_Type[1], by = BUYER]
DT2[SELLER != "", ID_Type := ID_Type[1], by = SELLER]
DT2
```

returns

> ```
>     ID_Type BUYER SELLER
>  1:       1          Joe
>  2:       0 Peter       
>  3:       0 Peter       
>  4:       1   Sam       
>  5:       0 Peter       
>  6:       0         Mark
>  7:       1   Tai       
>  8:       1   Tai       
>  9:       0         Mark
> 10:       1   Tai       
> 11:       1   Tai       
> 12:       1   Sam       
> 13:       3   Tom       
> 14:       3   Tom
> ```

where rows 10, 11, 12, and 14 are violating  the specification, IMHO.

The alternative solution

```
DT2[, cnt := cumsum(ID_Type == "0"), by = .(BUYER, SELLER)][
  cnt > 0L, ID_Type := "0"][, cnt := NULL]
DT2
```

returns

> ```
>     ID_Type BUYER SELLER
>  1:       1          Joe
>  2:       0 Peter       
>  3:       0 Peter       
>  4:       1   Sam       
>  5:       0 Peter       
>  6:       0         Mark
>  7:       1   Tai       
>  8:       1   Tai       
>  9:       0         Mark
> 10:       0   Tai       
> 11:       0   Tai       
> 12:       2   Sam       
> 13:       3   Tom       
> 14:       2   Tom
> ```

which is working according to specification as it changes only occurences of 0 in later rows.

Note that above solution is based on the implicit assumption that a name appears only in either of the two columns `BUYER` or `SELLER` but never in both.

#### Enhanced sample dataset

```
library(data.table)
DT2 <- fread(
  "ID_Type    |   BUYER   |    SELLER
  1       |           |    Joe
  0       |   Peter   |              
  1       |   Peter   |               
  1       |   Sam     |   
  1       |   Peter   |            
  0       |           |    Mark     
  1       |   Tai     |             
  1       |   Tai     |              
  1       |           |    Mark  
  0       |   Tai     |             
  1       |   Tai     |              
  2       |   Sam     |
  3       |   Tom     |
  2       |   Tom     |", 
  sep = "|", colClasses = c(ID_Type = "character"))
```